# AWS S3 soft delete objects

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I want to soft delete AWS S3 objects. What approach can I use? I searched tags and versioning. What is the best practice?

I can use the AWS console or the .Net SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by "soft delete"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [S3 object versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html). When you delete a versioned object, S3 simply writes a [deletion marker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html) to S3. You can later [delete the deletion marker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RemDelMarker.html) to reinstate the object.